# How to capture multiple matches between parenthesis using regex lookback

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture all the phrases in quotes and in between parenthesis in the the example below:

```
body paragraph text (the "first phrase to capture" or the "second phrase to capture").
```

So the following should be the matches: `"first phrase to capture"` and `"second phrase to capture"`.  I'm trying to use the negative lookbehind as below but I get an error saying lookbehinds need to be zero-width.  Is there another way to implement this using a regex?

```
(?<=\(.*)(".*?")(?=.*\))
```

[Link to example.](http://regex101.com/r/rD4iA0/3)

Comment: As a heads up for future questions, it's always wise to specify what language you plan to use a regex in (and/or add it as a question tag). Regex is implemented different in most languages and some things won't work depending on the "flavor".

Answer (score 2):

Should be enough to use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). See if this does what you want:

```
"[^"(]*"(?=[^(]*\))
```

- `"[^"(]*"` desired quoted parts
- `(?=[^(]*\))` lookahead to check if inside parenthesis

[Example at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lM9bG7/1); [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Note that this fails on parenthesis inside quoted strings like @Sam commented.

Comment: Fails on parenthesis inside of the quotes, which may work for OP (in which case this will be simpler than mine): `test("foo(bar)")ing`

Comment: @Sam didn't see any flavor specified so sticked with the most simple could think of

Comment: Some reason I thought I saw PCRE, so mine relies on that. Mine still won't work for nested parenthesis `(foo ("test") bar "fail")`. Have a +1 for a simpler solution.

Comment: This works great when either 1) both parens are in the string or 2) only the closing paren is in the string.  I still have some scenarios where the closing paren is on the next line: `"Don't match this" body paragraph text (the "first phrase to capture" or the "second phrase to capture" then wraps the line...`

Comment: @rkp333 It only works for balanced parenthesis. Possibly need to precheck the string, if there's an open without closing such as `\([^)]*$` and replace by `\0)` [see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lI3aF7/1)

Answer (score 2):

PCRE gives us nice access to tools like `\G` (match the end of the last match or the start of the string) and `\K` (discard matched items to the left) that make this doable:

```
(?:       (?# begin non-capturing-group)
  \(      (?# match start of the parenthesis)
 |        (?# OR)
  (?<!^)  (?# unless we are at the beginning of the string)
  \G      (?# start at the end of the last match)
)         (?# end non-capturing group)
[^)"]*    (?# match until end of the parenthesis or start of quote)
\K        (?# throw away everything to the left)
"([^"]*)" (?# capture 0+ characters inside double quotes)
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/dU8eT3/1)

Comment: Note that this will fail with nested parenthesis, since most regex engines can't "count" (I believe .NET has a way around this) to see how many parenthesis have been opened and if they are all closed yet. This means `(foo ("test") bar "fail")` will fail, since no parenthesis were opened since the last one was closed.

Comment: Also experimented with `\G` before I noticed no flavor was specified :P

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I am using Python so looks like the \G is not available there.